# Why would Remote Assistance work but not Remote Desktop?

Tags: security, windows-xp, remote-desktop

I have managed to get Remote Assistance working between two XP machines, but as soon as I try Remote Desktop I can't even get to the login screen without an error which gives a list of possibilities and concludes with "See your network administrator", which isn't very helpful.

I have ramped up the security level on Remote Desktop including turning on encryption etc.  Could this be the problem?  I will only get a few hours on the machine at a time so I need to be well-prepared before I attack this problem again.  Any ideas?

EDIT:  The error message is as follows, and this occurs before any login screen appears:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/7593c90b6e.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/7593c90b6e.png)

Comment: can you say, what exact error message is ? is two XP-Pro machines in domain or in workgroup ?

Comment: See the error message above. Two XP-Pro machines connected over the internet.

Comment: does thees XP-Pros has the same (latest) service pack ?

is there any errors at event log on remote PC ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that remote desktop is actually enabled on both machines? Remote Assistance tends to be enabled by defualt, but Remote Desktop not nessecarily. If you right-click on "my computer", choose "properties" and view the "remote" tab. Make sure the "allow users to connect..." is ticked.

Simple things first.

Comment: Remote Desktop is enabled and 'allow users to connect' is ticked.  Remote assistance works but Remote Desktop does not.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure port 3389 is open

Answer (score 0):

This message will also appear frequently if the same user unlocks the remote machine from another session: for example, if you RDP into the box as "Bob", but then "Bob" logs-in from his desk.